# numpy - Dibujando datos en gráfico de dispersión con X e Y del mismo tamaño

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, numpy

Tengo los siguients arreglos con algunos datos, y asociados en una lista de la siguiente manera usando zip:

```
X = np.array(list(zip(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,
                  f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18)))
print( " ARRAY X" +'\n', X, '\n' )

Y = np.array(list(zip(f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,f25,f26,f27,f28,f29,
                  f30,f31,f32,f33,f34,f35,f36,f37)))
print( " ARRAY Y" +'\n', Y, '\n' )
```

Y entonces con esto tengo la siguiente asociación de elementos:

```
ARRAY X
 [[0.27726829 0.         0.70441255 ... 0.17073171 0.53012048 0.39759036]
 [0.03315646 0.02175    0.19936204 ... 0.42073171 0.71686747 0.65060241]
 [0.28709117 0.         0.15948963 ... 0.41463415 0.3313253  0.38554217]
 ...
 [0.19825924 0.         0.33371671 ... 0.37849168 0.63201559 0.61497241]
 [0.19825924 0.         0.33371671 ... 0.37849168 0.63201559 0.61497241]
 [0.19825924 0.         0.33371671 ... 0.37849168 0.63201559 0.61497241]] 

 ARRAY Y
 [[0.43902439 0.52258065 0.33774834 ... 0.41975309 0.51315789 0.26060606]
 [0.69512195 0.68387097 0.59602649 ... 0.68518519 0.53947368 0.50909091]
 [0.67682927 0.66451613 1.         ... 0.56790123 0.44736842 0.08484848]
 ...
 [0.64469909 0.65824665 0.5558981  ... 0.6195577  0.5980531  0.44742931]
 [0.64469909 0.65824665 0.5558981  ... 0.6195577  0.5980531  0.44742931]
 [0.64469909 0.65824665 0.5558981  ... 0.6195577  0.5980531  0.44742931]]
```

Deseo ubicar en un gráfico de dispersión X e Y, pero obtengo este error:

```
plt.scatter(X, Y, c='black', s=17)
~/anaconda3/envs/sioma/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   4241         y = np.ma.ravel(y)
   4242         if x.size != y.size:
-> 4243             raise ValueError("x and y must be the same size")
   4244 
   4245         if s is None:

ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

Sé que la función de `scatter` necesita dos parámetros iterables `x` e `y` como puntos de coordenadas. Entonces, con la función zip, agrupo o asocio en X 18 elementos / columnas y en Y 19. Lógicamente necesita que ambos tengan el mismo número de elementos, de modo que un valor de `X` tiene su contrapartida en `Y`

Por supuesto, la forma de las columnas `X` e `Y` son diferentes:

```
print(X.shape)
(13807, 18)
print(Y.shape)
(13807, 19)
```

**Mi objetivo**

Quiero aplicar el algoritmo de K-Means, e inicialmente, mi objetivo es ubicar en un gráfico de dispersión los puntos del conjunto de datos, que he reunido en las matrices `X` e `Y`, que suman 37 columnas. Inicialmente, quiero ver en un gráfico de dispersión todos mis puntos de datos para verificar su ubicación antes de aplicar los algoritmos de agrupamiento de datos.

Debido a mi situación particular, intento reducir el número de elementos en mi matriz `X` de esta manera, obteniendo `f1_f2`

Intento reducir en 1 numero, la forma del array `X` de esta forma:

```
f1_f2 = np.array(list(zip(f1,f2)))
                      # I put here f1_f2    
X = np.array(list(zip(f1_f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,
              f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18,f19)))
Y = np.array(list(zip(f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,f25,f26,f27,
              f28,f29,f30,f31,f32,f33,f34,f35,f36,f37)))
```

... Pero ... por supuesto el array `f1_f2` es diferente de mis otros **`f`i** arrays, porque `f1_f2` es una columna que contiene arrays en lugar de floats (como mis otras **`f`i** columnas) y esas matrices son el resultado de agrupar dos columnas en una. 
Tal como lo menciona [FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/fjsevilla) en el comentario abajo.

[En esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47482672/2773461) explican un poco la situación, el arreglo o matriz debe ser construido con una secuencia lógica y ...

> Fail, can't convert a tuple into a numpy array element ...

```
print( " ARRAY X" +'\n', X, '\n' )
ARRAY X
        # ------- TUPLE ?--------
 [[array([0.27726829, 0.        ]) 0.7044125465178095 0.08053691275000001
  ... 0.5301204819277109 0.3975903614457832 0.4390243902439024]
 [array([0.03315646, 0.02175   ]) 0.19936204146730474 0.11162790698333333
  ... 0.7168674698795181 0.6506024096385544 0.6951219512195121]
 [array([0.28709117, 0.        ]) 0.1594896331738438 0.08988764045 ...
  0.3313253012048193 0.3855421686746988 0.6768292682926829]
 ...
 [array([0.19825924, 0.        ]) 0.3337167140951549 0.030059729580028987
  ... 0.6320155908754577 0.6149724073440681 0.6446990878406867]
 [array([0.19825924, 0.        ]) 0.3337167140951549 0.030059729580028987
  ... 0.6320155908754577 0.6149724073440681 0.6446990878406867]
 [array([0.19825924, 0.        ]) 0.3337167140951549 0.030059729580028987
  ... 0.6320155908754577 0.6149724073440681 0.6446990878406867]]
```

Luego, por razones obvias, cuando intento trazar los valores, obtengo este error

```
plt.scatter(X, Y, c='black', s=17) 
~/anaconda3/envs/sioma/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py 
in asanyarray(a, dtype, order)
    542 
    543     """
--> 544     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
    545 
    546 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

¿Cómo puedo ubicar en un diagrama de dispersión la totalidad de mis arrays `X` e `Y`, es decir, las 37 columnas que representan en total?

Sé que debería encontrar una forma de que las matrices `X` e `Y` tengan el mismo número de elementos, pero en este momento lo ignoro. Mi deseo es mostrar todos mis datos en la gráfica de dispersión antes de encontrar algunos grupos de datos o agrupamiento.

Lo que quiero es mostrar los datos asi de esta forma, solo que aquí estoy suprimiendo el array `f37` en `Y` para poder que X e Y tengan igual número de elementos:

```
X = np.array(list(zip(f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,f15,f16,f17,f18)))
Y = np.array(list(zip(f19,f20,f21,f22,f23,f24,f25,f26,f27,f28,f29,f30,f31,f32,f33,f34,f35,f36,))) # solo llega hasta f36
```

Y el gráfico es este:

```
plt.scatter(X, Y, c='black', s=17)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca me falta una columna o array de datos `f37`, que es importante de tener en cuenta.

---

Comment: No termino de entender que es lo que pretendes, `scatter` necesita dos iterables uno con los valores de las coordenadas x y otro con las coordenadas y de los puntos. Lógicamente necesita que ambos tengan el mismo número de elementos de forma que un valor de `X` tenga su homólogo en `Y`.  En el segundo caso lo que tienes es una columna que contiene arrays en vez de floats, y esos arrays son el resultado de agrupar dos columnas en una, el problema es que con esto un puntos quedaría definido por ejemplo con `x = 4.445`, `y = array([0.27726829, 0.        ])`... Por eso el segundo error.

Comment: @FJSevilla, En efecto, quiero visualizar mis matrices X e Y en un diagrama de dispersión, y el problema es una cantidad desigual de puntos de datos para X e Y. He aclarado un poco mas mi objetivo en mi pregunta